# hyperref problem if the link at the end of the page

Tags: hyperref, natbib

I am using

```
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
```

to allow breaklines in the hyperlink. However, when the citation link at the end of a page and breaks into a new page, it takes into consideration the chapter title of the page as shown in the attached image

[image].

Can anyone give me a tip of how I can solve this problem?
Note, I am using `natbib` package for citation.

Comment: Are you using `latex` or `pdflatex`? I've had reports of a similar issue with `glossaries` but it only seems to happen under certain circumstances, which I haven't been able to reproduce, so a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would help. (You can use the [lipsum](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) package to generate dummy text to fill the page.)